# QGIS 2.0 portable or silent installation

Tags: installation, qgis-2

Is it possible to install QGIS 2.0 unattended (silent) on Windows-Client (XP,7) via commandline ?

Or does there exists a portable version for 2.0 ?

Comment: I feel that the second part (portable installation) can be a separate question, since it is quite different.

Answer (score 6):

QGis installer is made by NSIS
try to execute this command line:

```
Qgisinstaller-name.exe /S
```

you can also execute uninstaller silently:

```
Qgisuninstaller-name.exe /S
```

reference :
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html